# Property values inside two prototype functions are not the same

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I initialize my this.interval=null in constructor, and then I want to change this last one in prototype.blink, but when I console it inside prototype.stopBlink() it gives null value

```
function Mesh(name, material) {
  this._name = name;
  this._material = material;
  this.interval = null;
}

Mesh.prototype.blink = function(obj, delay, box) {
  this.interval = (() => {
    var Toggle = true
    return setInterval(() => {
      if (Toggle)
        changeMaterial(obj, box);
      else {
        changeMaterial(obj, this._material);
      }

      Toggle = !Toggle;
    }, delay);
  })();

  console.log(this.interval);
}

Mesh.prototype.stopBlink = function(obj, duration) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.interval);

    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }, duration);
}
```

Comment: Did you check what is `this`? You know that it can be quite tricky in JS :)

Comment: You could pass an arrow function to `setTimeout` to capture the correct `this` like you do with `setInterval()` above.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I try it but this.interval still nulle and I change it in Blink() console give me 5420 !

Comment: and even if I console this.interval outside seTimeout() it gives me null !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example reduced to the main moving parts. It uses an arrow function inside `stopBlink`'s `setTimeout`. This is important because you want to capture the value of `this` lexically, not from the timeout call. It's not clear why you are using the immediately returned function inside `blink()`, but I left it:

```js
function Mesh(name) {
  this._name = name;
  this.interval = null;
}

Mesh.prototype.blink = function(delay) {
  var Toggle = false
  this.interval = (() => {
    return setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this._name, " blinking ", "Toggle", Toggle)
      Toggle = !Toggle;
    }, delay);
  })();
  console.log("interval in blink:", this.interval)

}

Mesh.prototype.stopBlink = function(duration) {

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("interval in stop: ", this.interval)
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }, duration);
}

let m = new Mesh("mesh")
m.blink(200)
m.stopBlink(1000)
```

Comment: lol thank u I have a big mistake in my code now I understand why this.interval is null despite using arrow function. because I use Html buttons to blink and stop blinking (2 buttons), the problem is that I define new Mash() every time I click so it works for blibking and when I click again it reset to null because of constrictor calling lol thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

Just as sjahan has written for you, in your setTimeout function, the this keyword is no longer pointing to the instance of the class, but rather to the window object.

use an arrow function instead, change

```
Mesh.prototype.stopBlink = function(obj, duration) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.interval);

    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }, duration);
}
```

to

```
Mesh.prototype.stopBlink = function(obj, duration) {

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.interval);

    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }, duration);
}
```

Comment: I try it but this.interval still null despite I console it in Blink() it has a value of 5420

Comment: @Anes his answer is correct. You need to change the setTimeout call in your stopBlink to take an arrow function instead so that `this` gets carried into the function.